# How can I rotate the viewport 180 degrees?

Tags: css

I was wondering what is the simplest way (ideally with CSS) to achieve this effect where the viewport rotates 180 degrees. Example here:

https://www.zakgroup.co.uk/projects/agenzia-indipendente-di-ricerca

(Note: This site is no longer live so don't waste your time looking for it like I did.)

Comment: Can you share your code and what you've tried?

Comment: hope this helps http://jsfiddle.net/dreamweiver/x6v60t2f/

Comment: Thank you Brett. Unfortunately, i have not tried anything yet as I'm not quite sure where to start. I have figured out that I may need to use Javascript for this as I want the events to occur on click.

Answer (score 0):

```
#container_2 {
   -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
   -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
   -o-transform: rotate(90deg);
   -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
   transform: rotate(90deg);
}

#container_2 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(180deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(180deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(180deg);
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to hover then you can use below code:

```
#container_2 {
    border: 1px solid;
    padding: .5em;
    width: 5em;
    height: 5em;
    transition: .3s all;  /* rotate gradually instead of instantly */
}

#container_2:hover {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);  /* to support Safari and Android browser */
    -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);      /* to support IE 9 */
    transform: rotate(90deg);
}

<div id="container_2">This box should be rotated 90&deg; on hover.</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. I've realised I may need to use some javascript to achieve this as I want this to occur on click.